# Cant add content to next page css html

Tags: html, css

im trying to press a button and go to the next html page but when i did connected it to the css and the page is completly empty.Can you tell me how can i make the page almost the same (with the same buttons at the left corner and the logo and the image) i need to add Contact information like text box First Name Second name etc to the new page but with the same layout as the first.This is what i got.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title >Personal Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/style.css">
    </head>
<body>                

<header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo"> 
            <img src="../logo.png">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="cont.html">Contact me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Georgi Matinski website</h1>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>

    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
     font-family:Century 'Times New Roman', Times, serif ;
}
header{
    background-image: url(../wa.jpg);
    height:100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
ul{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top:10px;
}
ul li{
    display:inline-flex;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    padding:5px 18px;
    border:1px solid transparent;  
    transition:0.8s ease;
}
ul li a:hover{
background-color: white;
color:black;
}
ul li.active a{
    background-color: white;
color:black;
}

.logo img{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
}
.title{
   font-size: small;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "arial";
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 30%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.title h1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
}

second html page 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/style.css">
    </head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want the same buttons that you have in your  UL ( home, contact, etc) you can copy-paste the section but if you want to show some info only if the user is connected you will need to switch from HTML to PHP that its almost the same, but now we can use PHP expressions .
so instead of "" home.html""  name it """home.php"" and what I would do its save the user name, and password in a data base, and output the code that you need only if the variable $user is a user in your data base, I guess using PHPMyAdmin (database)

I would do something like that
-session start to open our local session 
-require db.php would be a PHP script to connect your database to your files you can find some. examples online.
then we check if the user is conected, if not, we send it to error.php you need to create this file to a simple HTML file saying that you need to log in before seeing this and sending them home.

after that, you create a variable ( i called $content) and this variable is the buttons you wanted and we only show them if you are connected. I did this really quick if you have any questions write to me.

```
 `<?php
       session_start();
        require 'db.php';

      //Check if a user is logged in using      the  session variable

  if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
        header("location: ../error.php");    
  }
  else {
        // Makes it easier to read

      $username =     $_SESSION['username'];

      $variable = "anyInformation";

      $content  = "<ul> <li     class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> <li><a href="cont.html">Contact me</a></li> <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li> <li><a href="#">Info</a></li> </ul>";

  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
 <head> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/       style.css"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
   <?php 
             echo $content;
            echo $variable;
    ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The thing you explained is too complicated and i need a simple solution when i click on the button send me to the new page which i already did and there i just need to add some text boxes that don't do anything.Basically is the same for the other buttons 2 and when i want to go back to my home page i just click home.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to go back home  then you only need to add this to your second page 
I replaced the "#" by the filename "home.html" 
Did it was that that you wanted?
Also a upvote would be appreciated :)

```
<ul> <li class="active"><a   href="home.html">Home</a></li> <li><a href="cont.html">Contact me</a></li> <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li> <li><a href="#">Info</a></li> </ul>
```